# Find duplicates in lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `Integer` typed `ArrayList`, i would like to iterate through my list and being able to match all duplicates of the current index item.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     if(list.get(i) == list.get())//stuck here

//I want to scan the list if the current element has the same value to
//other elements while ignoring the value of my current index
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. What should the code return or print? "match every one" is not very clear. Give an example input, and an example output.

Comment: I don't have an output yet since i am stuck. I just want the for loop to matched every value in the `ArrayList<Integer>` while ignoring the current index aka the `i` in the for loop

Comment: If you don't know what the output **should** be, there is no way you can implement anything.

Comment: "_I just want the for loop to matched every value in the ArrayList<Integer> while ignoring the current index aka the i in the for loop_" is what i am trying to **achieve**.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
int currentIndex = 3;
T value = list.get(currentIndex);
Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();
for (int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
    T checkValue = it.next();
    if (i == currentIndex) continue;
    if (value != checkValue) continue;

    // whatever should take place in case of equality
}
```

I assume that with "duplicate" you really mean the same instance of an object being in the list and not to objects being equal. In that case `!value.equals(checkValue)` should be used (with additional checks for values not being null to prevent exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     // I have used Equal here but you can use "==" if you need to do         // it stronge
     list.stream().filter(t->!t.equal(list.get(i))).foreach(t->{
              // do what you want to do here
     })
}
```

Comment: `list[i]` (incorrect syntax) should be excluded from the filter.

Comment: @PM77-1 what is incorrect syntax ? List is arraylist right ?

Comment: @PM77-1  ohhh Yeah right :) Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is now completely wrong.  Please look at [Lothar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001551/2055998) and do **test** yours before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a more logical approach:

```
for(Object element : list){
   if(1<Collections.frequency(list,element)){ // count occurrences of the element
     ///
   }
}
```

Comment: Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> duplicates = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> list.get(i), Collectors.toSet()));